# How to execute a command on the remote at login with ssh, after .bashrc sourcing?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, environment-variables

I am working on different machines where my home is NFS-mounted. I want to switch easily to another machine if the one I am working on is too much loaded.

I often modify my environment in the shell I am working, and I would like to find the same modified (with respect to the bashrc) environment when I switch to another machine. I tried the following script, but it does not work because the .bashrc is sourced after `source $HOME/.env-dump.txt`.

Is there a clean way to execute some commands when logging to a machine with ssh as if you type them at the prompt after logged?

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

if [[ $# != 1 ]]; 
    echo 'sssh USAGE:'
    echo '  sssh remotename'
    exit 1
fi

printenv | sed -e '/_=.*/ d;s/\([^=]\+\)=\(.*\)/export \1="\2"/' > $HOME/.env-dump.txt
ssh $1 -t 'source $HOME/.env-dump.txt; bash -l'
```

Comment: The answer is to use the correct initialization file for what you are trying to do. For things that you want in non-interactive login shells don't use `.bashrc` use `.bash_profile` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following lines to your `~/.bash_profile`

```
[ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ] && . $HOME/bashrc
[ -f "$HOME/.env-dump.txt" ] && source $HOME/.env-dump.txt
```

And create a `~/.bash_logout` file with the line

```
[ -f "$HOME/.env-dump.txt" ] && rm  $HOME/.env-dump.txt
```

Now you can simply call `ssh $1 -t 'bash -l'` in the last line of your script.

**WARNING**

The output of `printenv` contains some variables which are machine dependent like `GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL`, `SESSION_MANAGER`, `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` ... (These variables are form a Ubuntu 12.04). These variables should be removed from the `~/.env-dump.txt` file.